# Get value of variable from unknown file

Tags: php

I am trying read php files so I can extract all of their variables and store them in an object.
Then I want to get the value of the variable and add that to the object too.
How can I get the value of the variable if it is in an unknown file?

**Code that parses files:**

```
function scan($file){
  $vars = (object) array();
  $tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($file));
  foreach($tokens as $token){
    if ($token[0] == 312){ //if the token is a variable
      $vars->{substr($token[1], 1)} = VALUE OF CURRENT TOKEN ;
    }
  }
  return $vars;
}
```

**Code that needs to be parsed:**

```
<?php

$duck = "cow";
$lizard = "cat";

?>
```

**Object that I want returned:**

```
{
  duck: "cow",
  lizard: "cat"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it terrible task. Only preg helps you. Something like this:

```
    <?php 

$filetext = '

<?php

$duck = "cow";
$lizard = "cat";
$qwert = 4;
$asdfg=2;

?>
';


preg_match_all('/\$(\w+)\s*=\s*(\S+);/', $a, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

if (!empty($matches[1])) {
    $object = new stdClass();
    foreach($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
        $object->{$value} = trim($matches[2][$key], '\'"');
    }
}
var_dump($object);
```